# Apex - Not able to exclude column in exported file

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an interactive report and the goal is to let the user export the data but without 1 column.
What I tried for the column in question:

```
1) Server-side condition - Request is NOT contained in value; Value - CSV, HTML
2) NVL(:REQUEST,'EMPTY') not in ('CSV','HTMLD')
```

The column I am trying to not export is a link with an icon. I tried changing it to 'Plain text' but to no avail.

Oracle Apex version 21.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to accomplish it using this:

```
instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'HTML') = 0 and instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'CSV') = 0
```

Comment: That worked to not download the column. In my case I want to download one column to Excel, so I write the expression instr(nvl(:REQUEST,'~'),'XLS') > 0 into the server-side-condition of this column, but it did not work, the column is not downloaded in the Excel file. Then I think I did not understand what this expression is doing!

Answer (score 0):

The approach described earlier worked for me with APEX 21.x.
However in APEX 22.1 the CSV download seems to be different; is this correct? For me the values are no longer evaluated again during download and thus I can not control this (we have a server side condition for that that accesses a page Item which we fill with a logic evaluating :REQUEST).